# Why sum with previous and current column do't working

Tags: mysql, sum, computed-column, mysql-8.0

> I want to update my specific row with that row previous value, after
>   searching i found some post about this but those solution not working
>   with me. So what is wrong with my query or how can i archive my goal.?

**This is my query:**

```
select d.innings_no,
       e.Player_Name,
       (@total := @total + ifnull(sum(b.runs_scored) + sum(c.extra_runs), 0)) as Runs,
       count(b.runs_scored)                                                      Balls
from wicket_taken d
       inner join ball_by_ball a on d.match_id = a.match_id and d.player_out in (a.striker, a.non_striker)
       left join batsman_scored b
                 on (a.match_id, a.over_id, a.ball_id, a.innings_no) = (b.match_id, b.over_id, b.ball_id, b.innings_no)
       left join extra_runs c
                 on (a.match_id, a.over_id, a.ball_id, a.innings_no) = (c.match_id, c.over_id, c.ball_id, c.innings_no)
       inner join Player e on d.player_out = e.Player_Id
       cross join
       (select @total := 0) params
where d.match_id = 335987
group by d.player_out, d.innings_no
order by d.player_out asc;
```

**This is my current output:**
[image]

**But i want those to be like this (previous column runs + current column runs):**

> 1  SC Ganguly  61  32
>
> 1  RT Ponting  112 (51+61) 41
>
> 1  DJ Hussey   172 (112+60)    30

**So how can i solve this.?**

Comment: Do you have MariaDB-10.2+ or MySQL-8.0? Because if you do Window functions provide an easier answer.  Can you show your tables with sample data to support your output.

Comment: my db is MySQL-8+, actually in that query i'm joining 5tables, so i'm not sure which table can i show. also those table only for learning purpose.

Comment: Take a look at [this very quick intro to window functions](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=1668)

Comment: i'm checking those.

Comment: Using user-defined variables: 1) with multiple tables 2) with group by 3) without proper ordering. Unpredictable result guaranteed. Obtain all another output fields and fields needed for UDV-calculations in subquery, then use UDV calculations in outer query with proper (unique!) records ordering.

Comment: thanks Akina, i'm new in this field and still in learning position, your those mentions points will help me to understand and learn.

Comment: Refine the algo of your query. You use `group by d.player_out, d.innings_no`. This means that `d.player_out` and `d.innings_no` may be NOT unique in a resultset. But then you use `order by d.player_out`. This gives unpredictable sorting result within a group with the same `d.player_out` and different `d.innings_no`, which will give non-deterministic UDV calculation results.

Comment: yeah, i'm improving my database query knowledge. i really learn new knowledge from your two comment. frankly telling before that i was not really sure why i'm using group by and order by but now i understand it. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "previous column runs"?  There is one column named `runs`.  Maybe you mean "previous row"?

Comment: yeah, i means row. sorry for my mistakes.